# Use volume and playback keys without waking the monitor?

Tags: monitor, multimedia, keys

Often my laptop is just standing around and just playing music and for the below mentioned actions I don't need to see wat's going on on my desktop.

Is it possible to use the volume and playback keys (no fn keys) of my keyboard to use

- volume up/down
- mute/unmute
- play/pause
- previous/next

without waking the monitor/display of the laptop?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this link [Turn off Screen with keyboard Shortcut in Ubuntu](https://alexcabal.com/turn-your-laptop-screen-off-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-ubuntu-karmic/)

Map the keys using gnome-keybinding-properties and lets see if it works for both music and the script.Script contains infinite loop which will turn off display after two seconds.
Do let me know if it didn't works,I'll try another work around.