# How to use keyboard keys without ending IDLE_MODE_BLANK?

Tags: unity, keyboard, monitor, multimedia, gnome-power-manager

**I want to change the volume without waking my laptop display up.**

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237706/use-volume-and-playback-keys-without-waking-the-monitor) wants to accomplish the same but has no usable answer (turning it off again is not an option as the environment is light-sensitive, the display has to stay off the entire time)

As display wakeup seems to be managed by `gnome-power-manager` I read [this](http://people.canonical.com/~bradf/power-management.html#idletime) ... 
which pointed me at `IDLETIME` ... 
which seems to be managed by [gnome-idle-monitor](https://github.com/endlessm/gnome-desktop/blob/master/libgnome-desktop/gnome-idle-monitor.c)....
which left me without leads as my C is too bad.

---

So to summarize: I want to be able to use some specific keys on my keyboard (e.g. volume keys) without resetting the `IDLETIME` counter -> 
 resulting in gnome not waking up my display)

**How can I accomplish this?**

---

**Update:** I don't care about the way (preventing `IDLETIME` reset / some other obscure dark magic), for me only the result - display staying off - matters.

---

**Update 2:** Also, [this shouldn't even happen](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Sound#Output.2Fvolume_change_notification) so why is my display waking up?!

Comment: Assuming laptop for obvious reasons, do you have a function (Fn) key to turn off display?,  here for me it's F2. So here,  Fn+F2 turns off the display until I hit Fn+F2 again, other key presses like for volume work but display stays off.

Comment: @doug That would have been nice. =( But no I don't have one, its a Lenovo W530. From what I gathered, it seems to be easier to just go with some of the available workarounds like disabling dpms on X, turning the display off with `vbetool` and implementing a script to wake it up again myself. `xrandr --output LVDS-1 --off` seems to work too but I hoped I can just get gnome behave properly from the beginning ...